# Can I use a ceiling tie above the level of the top wall plates?

Tags: framing, ceiling, roof

I'm beginning to research and design a DIY build of a fully insulated garden room.  Some key points:

- I'm in the South West of the UK, Wind zone 3 with very little/infrequent snow.
- I'm planning to stay more than 2m from my boundaries, so this will be classed as a permitted development, so long as the eaves height is a max of 2.5m, and the ridge a max of 4m.
- The internal floor space is less than 30m^2, so will not require building regulations approval.
- This question is about the roof - my diagram doesn't show the floor structure, I'm not intending to span 4.5m with a single joist.

The internal floor space will be 4.5x6.5m.  I'd like the room to not feel too vertically cramped when using it, so would like the majority of the headroom to be at least 2.1m.  I'm planning a warm roof, potentially with a living roof on top.
Having calculated roof loads, the total load of warm roof + potential living roof comes to 0.66kN/m^2.  Based on that, the span tables indicate I can use roof joists of 47x145mm at 600mm centres.

In order to keep the eaves below 2.5m, when taking floor joists and underfloor ventilation gaps etc into account, the maximum internal room size height right next to a wall is limited to 1880mm.  With a 15degree pitched roof, this rises to a comfortable 2.1m within 800mm of the wall or so - I can live with that.  However, with no other supports or ties, there's nothing preventing roof spread.  My intention in this plan would be to tie the joists together at a height of 2.1m, leaving the height clearance I'm looking for.  This would be done with another piece of timber the same size as the joists, and using plywood gussets to attach it to a pair of joists (along with a gusset at the ridge holding the joists together).

[image]

Finally, my question: Are ties at this level, and not attached directly to the wall plates, going to be sufficient to properly support the spreading loads generated in the roof:

- With a living roof and a total load of 0.66kN/m^2?
- If not, then without the living roof and a total dead load of 0.22kN/m^2 for just the deck and insulation?

Bonus question: If they *are* going to be sufficient, should they be on every joist pair, or could there be fewer of them spread throughout the space?

Comment: I have used drywall/Sheetrock on roofs like that, if there is high humidity I might use a wood sheet product if the garden room is going to be humid. Don’t want the drywall to sag. But I over on the other side of the pond, even though not inspected you would want it to hold up.

Comment: @EdBeal I haven’t decided whether to drywall or not yet - I may keep the beams exposed so the full height is visible to help keep it open, but if not then these ties will be where it goes. All the insulation etc will be above decking above the rafters in a warm roof.  Since writing the Q I’ve found documentation that rafter ties can be used within the lower third of the rafter height, so if I drop the tie by a couple of cm, it’ll be within that zone and should be fine.

Comment: Your terminology is different than ours I believe I understand and there would be no issue doing this in a residential setting.